# neo4j don' display node between two other nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have the following relations between two types of nodes (:Application, :City): *InstalledIn* and *UsedFrom* .

> App InstalledIn City
>   App UsedFrom City

This means an Application(Software) is installed in NewYork and used from London.

[image: Relationships]

Now I want to see the relations (UsedFrom) between cities. I want a view without applications. Users from city A use applcation from city B.
In the example above ( City London - AccessesApplicationIn NewYork )

how can i realise this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Adding data:

```
MERGE (a1:App {name:'app1'})
MERGE (a2:App {name:'app2'})
MERGE (c1:City {name:'London'})
MERGE (c2:City {name:'New York'})
MERGE (a1)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(c2)
MERGE (a2)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(c2)
MERGE (a1)-[:USED_FROM]->(c1)
MERGE (a2)-[:USED_FROM]->(c2)
```

[image]

2) Now we find the relationship between the cities:

```
MATCH (c1:City)<-[:USED_FROM]-(a:App)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(c2:City)
RETURN DISTINCT 'City ' + c1.name 
     + ' - [:AccessesApplicationIn] -> ' + 
       'City ' + c2.name 
AS AccessesApplicationIn
```

**AccessesApplicationIn**:

```
City New York - [:AccessesApplicationIn] -> City New York
City London - [:AccessesApplicationIn] -> City New York
```

**UPD**:

3) Another option of query:

```
MATCH path=(:City)-[r:AccessesApplicationIn]-(:City) DELETE r 
RETURN PATH
UNION
MATCH (c1:City)<-[:USED_FROM]-(a:App)-[:INSTALLED_IN]->(c2:City)
MERGE path=(c1)-[:AccessesApplicationIn]->(c2)
RETURN DISTINCT path
```

[image]

Comment: thanks alot - this works very well.
What can I do to get a graph out of this?

Comment: @Leo It is not clear what you need. Try to describe more clearly.

Comment: My Database is much bigger than the example. We have serveral applications per location. How can I avoid double relations? or is it possible to add a counter property?

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: N.p. - just add `DISTINCT` - http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-distinct - see updated.